# Summing values when merging rows in a data set in R

Tags: r, merge, summarize

So I have a large data set (50,000 rows and 500 columns).  I merged the rows I wanted to by this code:

```
Similarities <- Home %>%
  group_by_at(c(1,2,5,9,70,26)) %>%
  summarize_all(.funs = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ','))
```

In this code, for other the other rows that are combined and have different values, their output turns into a list separated with commas.  However, now I want to sum all the values in one specific column, in which I tried this code:

```
Similarities <- Home %>%
  group_by_at(c(1,2,5,9,70,26)) %>%
  summarize_at(.vars = FTR, .funs = function(x) paste(sum(x))),
  summarize_all(.funs = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ','))
```

I assumed it wouldn't work because I wasn't sure what I was doing.
My goal is to have the specific column: "FTR", when I merge rows together, all the values in "FTR" be added together.

An example of the data would be:

```
Total  Type  Clm   FTR     Loss

300    water  2      -103  N

200    fire   3      203   Y
 
300    water  2      100   Y
```

What my code does now is:

```
Total    Type   CLM  FTR        Loss
300      water  2    -103, 100  Y, N
200      fire   3    203        Y
```

But what I want is:

```
Total   Type   CLM    FTR   Loss
300     water   2    -3     Y, N
200     fire    3    203    Y
```

Comment: Why not just `.funs = sum` in `summarise_at`?

Comment: I do not want to sum all of the merged columns, I only want to sum 1 specific one

Comment: The column in `.vars` will be the only one. You should post data, please. Can you post the output of `dput(Home[1:20, 1:5])`?

Comment: I added an example of what I want the output to be vs. what it is doing now.  Also, I tried running that code but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sums the collapsed columns, like the question asks for.

```
special_sum <- function(x, sep = ", ", na.rm = TRUE){
  f <- function(y, na.rm){
    y <- as.numeric(y)
    sum(y, na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  x <- as.character(x)
  x <- strsplit(x, sep)
  sapply(x, f, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

WIth the second data.frame posted in the question, the function `special_sum` could be called as follows. The group columns are for tests purposes only.

```
Home <- read.table(text = "
Total    Type   CLM  FTR        Loss
300      water  2    '-103, 100'  'Y, N'
200      fire   3    203        Y
", header = TRUE)


Home %>%
  group_by(1, 2) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars('FTR'), special_sum)
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   1, 2 [1]
#    `1`   `2`   FTR
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2    -3
#2     1     2   203
```

Note that you should probably `sum` first then `paste` the values.

Comment: @Anna To see the data like R sees it, please post the output of `dput(Home[1:20, 1:5])` in the question.